# Returning objects that work with parent object's data and later invalidate them

Tags: c++, api, qt

I'm working on an implementation of tables in a Qt app, but having a bit of trouble getting the design right.

I have two classes, `Table` and `Cell`.

`Cell` has API for setting cell properties such as borders and paddings, and getting the row and column of the cell using `int Cell::row()` and `int Cell::column()`. It is an explicitly shared class, using [QExplicitlySharedDataPointer](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qexplicitlyshareddatapointer.html) for its data. It also has an `isValid()` API to query if the cell is valid or not.

`Table` has API for inserting/removing rows and columns and merging areas of cells. A `Cell` may be retrieved from a table using `Table::cellAt(int row, int column)`. Rows of cells are kept as a `QList<QList<Cell>>`. When rows and columns are removed, the removed cells are marked as invalid by the table, which makes calls to `Cell::isValid` on any previously returned cells from the removed rows/columns return false.

Now to the tricky part: Since calculating the row and column number of a cell if you haven't already got them is an expensive operation, the `Table::cellAt(int row, int column)` methods sets the row/column explicitly on the `Cell` before returning it and the `Cell` keeps them as simple `int` members. This means a `Cell` can reply fast when queried for its row/column.

But here comes the problem; This also means that the values of `Cell::row()` and `Cell::column` will be incorrect if rows or columns are removed/inserted before the row/column that the cell is in.

I can't mark the affected cells as invalid in the same way I do when the actual row/column they are part of is removed. Since later on someone might again retrieve a cell with `cellAt(int, int)` in that row/column. And that cell should not be invalid.

Does anyone have some advise on a better design here?

Comment: I'm starting to think that keeping the row/column info in the cells updated every time rows/columns are inserted/removed from the table is the only right answer to this question? Instead of setting it when the cell is returned from `Table::cellAt(int, int)`. But eager to hear advice from more experience people!

Comment: I suppose this is about performance. Am I right?

Answer (score 2):

You could do a lazy update. That is, instead of updating the cell's position information every time the table changes, only update it when `Cell:row` or `Cell:column` are called if the table has changed since the last time the cell's position was updated. That would require you to keep a version stamp or something in `Table` and `Cell`. Every time the table gets updated, bump the version. `Cell::row` and `Cell:column` would first check if the `Cell`'s version is older than the `Table`'s, and if so, recalculate the position.

Whether that extra work is worth it versus just always recalculating position or recalculating on every change, I can't say.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's one approach. However for my purposes it is much more important that the cellAt(int, int) API return quickly than it is that operations for inserting/removing rows/columns do, so I'm really starting to think that keeping the row/column on the cells always updated is the right approach for me.

Answer (score 0):

I discussed this problem with a friend because it seemed too much like a Programming Pearls exercise. This is what we came up with:

- Create a new structure for counting indices. It could be something like `struct Index { int n; };`.
- Store row and column indices in two `QList<Index*>`. Let's call these `Dimension`. Using a pointer is crucial, as you'll see later.
- Cells do not store their row and column values anymore. They point to an element at each of the two `Dimension`. When queried for their row and column, there is now an extra pointer dereference which should not be too expensive.
- When the table has rows and columns added or removed, you add items to or remove items from the corresponding `Dimension` and update the `n` value of the following items. Storing pointers is necessary because `QList` copies its values.

Instead of renumbering every Cell affected by a table manipulation, an operation that has a cost of O(*rows* x *columns*), you'll now update only the affected rows or columns, which has cost of O(*rows* + *columns*). The downside is added code complexity and two dereferenced accesses when the Cell is queried for its row or column.

Comment: Hm, interesting approach. I'll have to think about it a little. Wouldn't a `QList<int*>` suffice in this case though, or would I have to create a new struct?

Comment: Yeah, QList<int*> is enough. Why did I use a struct? I need some rest.